# c remove space function stops when space is hit

Tags: arrays, c

I'm creating a function in c where if there is a space in a char array, it will remove it and print the array. The problem i'm having is that when I hit a space, the function stops copying the rest of the array to the final string.

this is the code:

```
void removeSpace(char *str) {
    char *temp = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp, str);
    str = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++) {
        while (temp[i] == ' ') {
            i++;
        }
        str[i] = temp[i];
        printf("str i: %c, temp i: %c\n", str[i], temp[i]);
    }
    printf("str: %s\n", str);

}
```

And this is inside the "main" function:

```
int main(main) {
    char *test = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(test, "hello world");
    removeSpace(test);
```

The result I get is this:

```
str i: h, temp i: h
str i: e, temp i: e
str i: l, temp i: l
str i: l, temp i: l
str i: o, temp i: o
str i: w, temp i: w
str i: o, temp i: o
str i: r, temp i: r
str i: l, temp i: l
str i: d, temp i: d
str: hello
```

If anyone could help I would appreciate it!!!

Comment: You need a separate counter for your destination array, when you skip the space, you put nothing at the 'i'th position in str, and then keep going.  I imagine you are compiling in debug mode, and the compiler is kindly handing you zeroed memory, so there is a '\0' character in the str array when you skip the space, thus terminatin g the string.  If you compiled in optimized mode, you may see a garbage character there instead of a space.

Comment: `while (temp[i] == ' ') i++;` would be UB if you have a space as the last char in the string. Replace with: `if (temp[i] == ' ') continue;`

Comment: Why would `str[i]` and `temp[i]` have different values in a line of code immediately following an assignment where you made them the same: `str[i] = temp[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few issues here. Some minor ones first.

The first thing you do is `malloc` some memory, but don't `free` it, so it'll leak. As a side note, you don't need to copy the `str` parameter at the start, since you're making a copy of it anyway.

I'll assume this is just an exercise, so the fact that you're just making a guess that the string is less than 1000 characters doesn't matter, but even so, you could take the length of first to allocate the right size of memory.

Because of the way C strings work, `strlen()` finds the length by scanning from the beginning until it finds a `'\0'` character, so `for (...; i < strlen(temp); ...)` will scan the whole string every time through the loop. The source length doesn't change, so save it in a `const` variable and compare to that in the loop.

The root of the problem is that you're using the same index `i` for `str` as for `temp`. When you skip characters in `temp`, you want to use a different index for `str` which is not incremented. Something like this might work (I haven't tested it):

```
void removeSpace(char *str) {
    const size_t str_len = strlen(str);
    const size_t str_size = str_len + 1; // include '\0'
    char *temp = malloc(str_size * sizeof(char));

    // Copy str to temp but skip ' '.
    int temp_idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str_size; i++) {
        while (str[i] == ' ') {
            i++;
        }
        temp[temp_idx] = str[i];
        temp_idx++;
        printf("temp i: %c, str i: %c\n", str[i], temp[i]);
    }
    printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!!! I've been stuck on this for hours and now I feel dumb since the answer seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

> it will remove it and print the array.

**Alternative: If OK to change the input string**

Walk the string and copy the non-string portion back on itself.

```
void filter_out_spaces_and_print(char *src) {
  char *origin = src;
  char *dest = src;
  while (*src) {
    if (*src != ' ') {
      *dest++ = *src;
    }
    src++;
  }
  *dest = '\0';
  printf("%s", origin);
}
```